# Are lightsabers flat?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I've always thought of lightsaber blades as dowel-shaped, but if you look at some of the lightsaber fights in the original movies, there are points where it momentarily looks flat like looking at a sword blade edge-on. That might just be artifacts of early effects technology, since I haven't noticed anything similar in the newer movies. However, the darksaber is very clearly rendered as flat, but also clearly a very unique weapon.

So, as in the title, are lightsaber blades flat like a sword, or round like a dowel?

Comment: Maybe both. The dark saber has a flat blade.

Comment: out of universe, the film CGI technology was not that great at that time, lightsabers were hand drawn using rotoscoping (AFAIK)

Comment: @Max This [Corridor Digital video](youtube.com/watch?v=Lh1Tz3zwhFU) shows some of the techniques used for OG Star Wars VFX. Some shots the lightsabers were hand drawn, but they also used other techniques elsewhere.

Comment: For the benefit of old fogies like myself, the Darksaber referred to above is this one: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber

For the youngsters that don't know why I'm bothering to mention this, I first thought of this Darksaber: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber_(superweapon)

Comment: Having seen a docu on how Episode IV was made (many, _many_ years ago), they actually did the fights with lightsaber handles with 2 electrified rods sticking out of them then "painted" the saber blade over it in post. That way, when they hit blades, there was physical contact and a natural reaction in their bodies. Therefore, when 2 blades touch in the movie, they may be closer than you'd think because the two bars each make a flat surface, and the 2 flat surfaces act more as a "sword" than a "rod".

Comment: @TylerH no, the [darksaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber) is a lightsaber, created by the Mandalorian Jedi Tarre Vizsla. (Or from [this more official source](https://www.starwars.com/databank/darksaber): "An ancient lightsaber that serves as a powerful symbol of leadership to the Mandalorians, the Darksaber is a unique weapon with a black-energy blade lined with a crackling white edge.")

Comment: The propmasters in the films explicitly used aluminum and carbon-fiber cores for the prop lightsabers. You can tell TESB/RotJ and the prequel films used aluminum rods because in several BTS shots the blades are clearly made from metal, plus the stunt coordinator can be seen bending the blades back after they were bent out of shape from too much whacking. They might have used carbon fiber blades as well, but in the sequel trilogy they had LED blades to provide dynamic illumination on the scenes. In any case, all blade cores in the movies are round.

Answer (score 52):

Lightsaber emitters are typically round:

[image: lightsaber emitter]

Also, if these lightsabers were anything other than round you would expect them to appear differently depending on the relative angle between the viewer and the lightsaber. However, you can usually see that the dimensions of the lightsaber beam are consistent from every angle, which implies they are circular.

The very first time we saw a lightsaber in Star Wars, Luke holds it at a variety of angles:

[image: Luke testing out the lightsaber]

(EDIT: though here is an example like OP mentioned where there are brief moments where it appears flat, oh well.)

And as OP and Jack B Nimble mentioned the Darksaber appears to have a flat blade.

The Darksaber's hilt is noticeably different from the typical round emitters:

[image: darksaber hilt]

And when it is moved around by characters wielding you can see that from some angles it appears wider and others more narrow, which is what you would expect for a flat blade. This is demonstrated nicely in this gif:

[image: Sabine holding darksaber]

The Darksaber is a unique kind of lightsaber and thus this difference reinforces the idea that lightsabers are typically round.

Here are a couple more shots that seem to show a round blade:

[image: Rey]

[image: Darth Vader]

And finally, for what it's worth, note that the lightsaber props have sometimes been wooden dowels, which are round. If they were going for something other than round, they'd probably have used something else.

[image: wooden dowels]

EDIT: another thought I had was that really you could only know the answer to this if you were looking at a canon-confirmed lightsaber in 3D. Fortunately, there's a canon VR game ["Vader Immortal"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vader_Immortal:_A_Star_Wars_VR_Series) that features lightsabers. I haven't played it but I suspect the lightsabers look pretty round in VR. Can't say definitively from [this gameplay video](https://youtu.be/eHPD2zQpzxg?t=1089) but seems round to me.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments by @aleppke, you can look at the holes lightsabers make. An example I found of this is in Clone Wars (the hole there looks pretty circular to me):

[image: Ventress stabbing trooper, Clone Wars]

Comment: I'm assuming a full digression into the fascinating history of the original lightsaber props from Ep. IV is out-of-scope here? The dowels were only used later, when it was discovered that post-production rotoscoping was required anyways.

Comment: Updated the word choice slightly

Comment: I think the real answer is lightsabers in the original release of *Star Wars* (episode IV) were not fully round/cylindrical, but since then they have been. There’s definitely strange stuff in the original version of the fight between Vader and Kenobi

Comment: If you have more information you should add it as answer 

Comment: @ToddWilcox For sure, but that was an artifact of low-quality FX and not an intentional in-universe thing. As with many of the dodgy FX shots in the originals, Lucas has gone back and fixed them with CGI since. YMMV on the other CGI of course, but those shots are pretty unambiguously better.

Comment: I wonder if we could find/recreate a version of that first gif (with Luke) post-special edition, with the CGI fixed to make it round?  Would be good to see them side-by-side.

Comment: I think that gif is at least from one of the newer versions, since iirc the older versions have the lightsaber looking more white than blue.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNbzSH84mj0 doesn't seem to note any differences between the original and remastered versions for that scene, though maybe there were changes later on?

Comment: @Graham Agreed, which brings up the distinction that perhaps lightsabers were always *meant* to be cylindrical but in some cases appear flat (saber-like) in the original ep IV. It’s conceivable that one of the rotoscope artists on the first film deliberately made it look more like a saber because of the name.

Comment: In the clip of Luke holding a lightsabre for the first time, it looks like the widening was supposed to be motion blur—as in the blade itself widening in the direction of motion because it takes the plasma some time to reach the tip and get back to the emitter—that is sometimes overdone for slow movement.

Comment: The shape of the blade can also be seen from the shape of the holes it creates. In Episode I, Qui Gon pushes his lightsaber through a door and begins slicing. A shot of the other side of the door clearly shows a circular hole where the lightsaber first pierced the door: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K48M2S7bkSA (apologies for the 1 hour loop, it was the first result that came up).

Comment: *"...the dimensions of the lightsaber beam are consistent from every angle, which implies they are circular.* Not necessarily circular, but that their cross sections are [curves of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width). And possibly even different cross sections at different points. Greetings from math.se.

Comment: The assumption is that the blade is either flat or round, if you want to start talking about other shapes I'm leaving :P

Comment: @aleppke that's a good point, though I don't think you can definitively say from that particular clip that the hole is round, mainly because of all the melting metal in the way — but it's certainly open to interpretation.

Comment: @aleppke, I added another example based on your suggestion

Answer (score 17):

The original 1977 film (which you can't really see anymore) used mechanical beams to simulate swords. These beams were circular and, if you see the non-special edition, you can even make out the beam from the final cut (where Obi-Wan is circling Vader's saber with his own and the pole itself is visible for a split second when the tube is aimed directly at the camera)

Any "flat" looks may be due to the fact that they edited the original films to have a better glowing effect, more consistent with the prequel trilogy.

Comment: What is a "mechanical beam" in this context?

Comment: @shim That's how they describe it in the video. It's not metal (Mark Hamill describes how often they would break), but they had to be sturdy enough to duel with, while reflecting enough light for the original rotoscope effect. They almost looked fiberglass.

Comment: actually they weren't sturdy enough to duel with.  In the whole fight between obi wan and darth vader they never touched saber props, because when they hit eachother they broke.  Later on they used metal version, but when they discovered tiny bits of metal were flying on impact they had to cover them in shrinkrap.  =)

Comment: [This fandom page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber) uses the term "carbon rod" though honestly that isn't any more informative than "mechanical beam" lol (at least a rod is implicitly round though)

Comment: you can see an example of one of the original ANH blades in special features on various DVD's also in the "Extras" section on Disney+ for 'A New Hope' - it's some sort of metal rod coated w/ reflective material. They had hoped that just shining a light on the rod would be enough of an effect in itself, but it wasn't what they hoped so they did the rotoscoping

Comment: You can't *non-questionably-legally* see them anymore. [Harmy's Despecialized Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmy%27s_Despecialized_Edition) - However, "As of January 2020, he had received no legal challenge from Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures, the owner of Lucasfilm and 20th Century Studios, over the Despecialized Edition."

Comment: @shim It's most likely "being" not "beam", referencing Darth Vador who is "only partially a man and mostly a mechanical being".

Comment: Can’t tell if you’re joking or not...

Answer (score 0):

The expanded universe canon--at least before Disney decanonized all of it--was that lightsabers were consisted of a flat, but very thin loop of flowing plasma magnetically confined to the handle, and that they do technically have an "edge", being more effective slicing along the edge than against it, though it can't be seen due to how brightly it glows.

This also was presented as an explanation for why only force-sensitive people can wield them effectively; the huge current and strong magnetic fields (including interaction with the magnetic field of any planet you're on, presumably) meant it would pull sideways when swung, and you needed to be able to predict and account for that, which was only really feasible for those who could use the force for that, though in theory possible for someone who's just *very* good with them.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @shim I'm afraid I don't remember which book it was that I read that in.

Comment: In *Traitor*, lightsabers are explicitly described as round and containing no edge - though they are all "edge" in the sense that every part of the blade cuts equally well.

Comment: @shim Now that I think on it, it may have been in one of the KOTOR games. I don't recall which, and I don't exactly have the time to replay them to find the source, but if someone else can find it I'll happily add it to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

They are round. You’re right about the Darksaber though, it’s flat because it’s a unique lightsaber but normal ones are usually round. However, the blade of a lightsaber is pure light. And light can give off different shapes and effects depending on the angle that you look at it. Your brain can manipulate light in so many different ways. But I think it’s just old filming quality.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these assertions?